# Comparing special characters in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a function I have written that outputs coloured output kind of like this:

```
foo() {
  local arrow="\033[1;32m↑\033[0m"
  echo "1$arrow"
}
```

I'd like to test this function so I'm using https://github.com/kward/shunit2 to do unit tests for it.

```
test_foo() {
  local green_arrow="\033[1;32m↑\033[0m"
  assertEquals "1$green_arrow" "$(foo)"
}
```

But shunit complains that: `ASSERT:expected:< 1↑> but was:< 1↑>`. I'm guessing there's a problem with hidden characters being output by the function.

Is there any way to strip special characters, or escape them from the variable?

---

Edit:

Running the following commands shows that the `\\033` escape character is being converted, probably by echo, into a literal `\E` escape:

```
printf '%q' "1$green_arrow"
' 1\\033[1;32m?\206\221\\033[0m'

printf '%q' "$(foo)"
' 1\E[1;32m?\206\221\E[0m'
```

Comment: `printf %q` is your friend, if you want to see this in printable form.

Comment: That is to say: `printf 'Comparing %q against %q\n' "1$green_arrow" "$(foo)"`

Comment: BTW, there's an obvious difference here in terms of the leading space before the `1`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yep, obvious copypasta, will fix. `%q` is a good trick, here's the result: `Comparing $' 1\\033[1;32m?\206\221\\033[0m' against $' 1\E[1;32m?\206\221\E[0m'`

Comment: Also, the output from `printf %q` is something you can directly use in your source file as a literal for assignment purposes, so you can use `green_arrow=$' 1\E[1;32m?\206\221\E[0m'`.

Comment: BTW, whether `echo` runs that conversion itself is not something POSIX standardizes -- part of why `printf` is preferred. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, particularly APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your help, `printf -v <variable name> '<content to escape>'` and then comparing against that works well. Can you clean up your answer below to reflect only that and the `printf %q <variable name>` part since it would be useful for others in the future and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `printf -v varname_quoted %q "$varname"` to get escaped forms of your content will provide an easier-to-read and easy-to-reason-about form, which can also be included in your code as literals with no additional quoting or escaping needed. (This can be simplified to `printf %q "$varname"` if your goal is to emit quoted content to stdout, rather than to another variable).

---

That is to say, to get a format string to a literal (with support in the format string for arguments, ie. `%s`, `%02f`, etc):

```sh
printf -v green_arrow '\033[1;32m↑\033[0m'
```

...or, a backslash-escaped string (which supports only a subset of full format-string syntax) to a literal:

```sh
printf -v green_arrow '%b' '\033[1;32m↑\033[0m'
```

...and then, to get that literal emitted in escaped, human-readable form for easy comparison and/or copy-and-paste into shell scripts as a literal:

```sh
printf '%q\n' "$green_arrow"
```

---

Tying this all together, the following is one way to get a more readable error message (please pardon StackOverflow's syntax highlighting, which as of this writing doesn't fully grok the way nested quoting contexts work in bash):

```sh
test_foo() {
  local green_arrow=$'\E[1;32m↑\E[0m'
  assertEquals "$(printf '%q' " 1$green_arrow")" "$(printf '%q' "$(foo)")"
}
```

...or, more efficiently (avoiding the unnecessary subshells):

```sh
test_foo() {
  local green_arrow=$'\E[1;32m↑\E[0m'
  local desired_answer_quoted actual_answer_quoted
  printf -v desired_answer_quoted '%q' " 1$green_arrow"
  printf -v actual_answer_quoted  '%q' "$(foo)"
  assertEquals "$desired_answer_quoted" "$actual_answer_quoted"
}
```